# C++ OpenCV triangle detection using hough transform

Tags: c++, opencv, detection, hough-transform, triangular

I'm looking for some examples how to implement hough transform for triangles detection. It's for sign detection needed. I've already done color thresholding. What do you think about using `HoughLinesP()`? I'm doing Canny, then thresholding and using HoughLines, but the result is many of lines and there are inside my sign too. I don't think finding intersection now will be my solution.

What do you think? Any examples or other ideas? I've also tried `findContours()`, but the triangles are rounded, so they need big approximation and it makes detecting full of trash.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it will be very difficult to use `HoughLinesP` for this task, because it's unstable and strongly depends on preprocessing of input images and parameters. Some time ago I solved similar task and I sugest you following processing pipeline (assuming input image is grayscale):

1. `cv::blur` for image enhancement
2. `cv::MSER` to find regions (need to tune parameters here). You may want to reject small regions.
3. For each region:

   3.1. `cv::convexHull` to find convex hull of region.

   3.2. Do `cv::approxPolyDP` for convex hull with increasing `epsilon` parameter until it returns 3 or less polylines. You may reject regions with number of lines less than 3.

   3.3. Finally you can calculate angles between lines and check that it's triangle. If all angles closer to 60 degrees (or just less 90 degrees) mark this region as triangle.

I hope it will help. If you will solve this task successfully, please describe your experience here.

Comment: I'm trying this now, but without fine results

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the lines number is extremaly high or one. This is my code:

```
#define red 10, 180, 180, 25, 255, 255

    void SetScalars(int h1, int s1, int v1, int h2, int s2, int v2){
        color_min = Scalar(h1, s1, v1);
        color_max = Scalar(h2, s2, v2);
    }

    void triangles(){
    ToHSV();
    SetScalars(red);
    Thresh();
    Mat dst = frame.clone();
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    blur(frame_thresh, frame_thresh, Size(3, 3));
    MSER(15,250,1000,0.15)(frame_thresh, contours);
    // Find the convex hull object for each contour
    vector<vector<Point> >hull(contours.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        int vtc = hull[i].size(); 
        convexHull(Mat(contours[i]), hull[i], false);
        approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), hull[i], arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true) * 0.1, true);
        cout << vtc << endl;
        if (vtc == 3){
            vector<double> cos;
            cos.push_back(angle(hull[i][0], hull[i][1], hull[i][2]));
            cos.push_back(angle(hull[i][1], hull[i][2], hull[i][0]));
            cos.push_back(angle(hull[i][0], hull[i][2], hull[i][1]));
            sort(cos.begin(), cos.end());
            double mincos = cos.front();
            double maxcos = cos.back();
            if (vtc == 3 && mincos > 0.4 && maxcos < 0.6){
                Rect r = boundingRect(contours[i]);
                Mat croppedImage = dst(r);
                imshow("detected triangle", croppedImage);
            }
        }
    }
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(frame_thresh.size(), CV_8UC3);
    for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
    {
        drawContours(drawing, contours, i, Scalar(0,0,255));
        drawContours(drawing, hull, i, Scalar(255, 0, 255));
        int vtc = hull[i].size();
    }
    imshow("mser", drawing);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [Generalized Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_Hough_transform) which is a generalization of Hough transform to detect arbitrary shapes. This way, you can specify your shape as a triangle.

There is an implementation of Generalized Hough in OpenCV:
http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dd4/classcv_1_1GeneralizedHough.html
and you can use the setTemplate method to define your shape.